# PHP Regex pulling text after period and before space

Tags: php, regex

I'm attempting to pull a certain part out of different varying strings, and am having a really hard time getting the correct regex to do so. Here are a few examples of what I am trying to pull from:

1. AG055.MA - MAGNUM (Want to return just MA)
2. WI460.16 - SOMETHING (Want to return 16)
3. AG055.QB (Want to return QB)

So basically, I just want to pull the characters after the period, but before the space. Nothing else before or after. Can someone give me a hand with getting the correct regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php
preg_match( '/\.([^ ]+)/', $text, $matches );

print_r( $matches );
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => .MA
    [1] => MA
)

Array
(
    [0] => .16
    [1] => 16
)

Array
(
    [0] => .QB
    [1] => QB
)
```

The regex is saying find a . character, then get any characters after it that are not a space character. The + makes it only return matches where there is a non-space character after the dot.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match('/\w+\.(\w{2})\s/', $input, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

- `\w+` means 1 or more word characters (a-z, A-Z and 0-9).
- `\.` means the period/dot (the backslash is to escape it, because `\.` is used as an operator in regex)
- `(\w{2})` matches 2 word characters
- `\s` means whitespace

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9]{5}\.([A-Z0-9]{2})/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Should return the characters in `$matches[1]`.